# My nav toggler icon is not displayed but while clicked on that region it works fine. What can I do to resolve this

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

After setting custom background for the `nav-bar` in bootstrap 4, I tried to put `nav-toggler-icon` for small screens. the nav-bar hamburger icon is not displayed but when I click the region it works fine. What can I do for it.
The  html code is:

```html
<nav id=header-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-custom ">
      <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
        <h1 class="tagline">Subha</h1>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburger">
            <span class=" navbar-dark navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburger">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Cart</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

the css code for nav bar is:

```css
.navbar-custom
{
 background-color: rgb(144,12,25);
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
data-target="#hamburger"
```

to

```
data-target="#navbarResponsive"
```

I hope this helps you! Otherwise take my own navbar template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="Logo" /></a>
            <!-- dropdown btn -->
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <!-- nav-links -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">about</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">team</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link">connect</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: if I change the data target then how can it perform the toggling action without targeting the link.

Comment: ye I didn't explain it well, forget what I said

Answer (score 0):

Your `<nav>` is missing the color [**scheme color**](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navbar/#color-schemes) class, Which is what bootstrap uses to add the icon to the button.

The problem is you misplaced it, it should go on the `<nav>` not the `<span>`, It's only visible when you click it because the an outline as applied.

**Demo**

```css
body {
  zoom: 2;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="navbar-light bg-primary">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="navbar-dark bg-primary">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</div>
```

---

Solution

```css
.navbar-custom {
  background-color: rgb(144, 12, 25);
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav id=header-nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark navbar-custom ">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand">
    <h1 class="tagline">Subha</h1>
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburger">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburger">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Cart</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```